# How to set one datepicker selected date is firstdate for another datepicker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have two date picker field contract start date and contract end date. when I am selecting a contract start date then for contract end date initial value or first date is selected date of the first date picker.

here I have a code for both date pickers.

```
  Widget _buildContractBeginDate() {
    return DateTimeField(
      format: format,
      autocorrect: true,
      autovalidate: false,
      controller: _contractBeginDate,
      readOnly: true,
      validator: (date) => (date == null || _contractBeginDate.text == '')
          ? 'Please enter valid date'
          : null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Contract Begin Date",
          hintText: "Contract Begin Date",
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.calendar,
            size: 24,
          )),
      onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
        return showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          firstDate: DateTime(1900),
          initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
          lastDate: DateTime(2022),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContractEndDate() {
    return DateTimeField(
      format: format,
      autocorrect: true,
      autovalidate: false,
      controller: _contractEndDate,
      readOnly: true,
      validator: (date) => (date == null || _contractEndDate.text == '')
          ? 'Please enter valid date'
          : null,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Contract End Date",
          hintText: "Contract End Date",
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.calendar,
            size: 24,
          )),
      onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
        return showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            firstDate: DateTime(1900),
            initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
            lastDate: DateTime(2022));
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a demo which is somewhat similar to yours please refer it:

TL;DR: Use `ValueNotifier<DateTime>` and update it's value from first date picker and always use that Notifier's value as first date for second date picker. You will always get an updated date this way.

[***Run code on Dartpad***](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f8c95ba18b9be46d3f0374c378fdae76)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(home: MyApp()),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  ValueNotifier<DateTime> _dateTimeNotifier = ValueNotifier<DateTime>(DateTime.now());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Demo')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildContractBeginDate(context, _dateTimeNotifier),
          _buildContractEndDate(context, _dateTimeNotifier),          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _buildContractBeginDate(BuildContext context, ValueNotifier<DateTime> _dateTimeNotifier) {
     return RaisedButton(
       child: Text('Begin Date'), 
      onPressed: () => showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            firstDate: DateTime(1900),
            initialDate: _dateTimeNotifier.value,
            lastDate: DateTime(2022), 
            ).then((DateTime dateTime) => _dateTimeNotifier.value = dateTime),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContractEndDate(BuildContext context,ValueNotifier<DateTime> _dateTimeNotifier) {
    return RaisedButton(
       child: Text('End Date'), 
      onPressed: () {
        return showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            firstDate: _dateTimeNotifier.value,
            initialDate: _dateTimeNotifier.value ?? DateTime.now(),
            lastDate: DateTime(2022));
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment.

Comment: I am happy that I could help :)